# Something in my VIM gvimrc file that's stopping the cursor from wrapping?

Tags: vim, text-cursor

I have been currently tweaking my Vim `_gvimrc` file to add a few features etc. and I've recently noticed, that when I use the cursor key to move left while at the beginning of a line, it no longer moves to the end of the previous one, it just stays put.

I used to be able to move from line to line just by holding the left or right cursor keys but for some reason that functionality has been lost. This is also true for the standard Vim `h j k l` keys.

Comment: Not off topic - FAQ says SO permits questions on "_software tools commonly used by programmers_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:set whichwrap=b,s,h,l
```

`whichwrap` can be abbreviated to `ww`.